# How to Convert Webelement to Double?

Tags: java, selenium

I have one dropdown in web with a list of Double values and I have to convert that `WebElement` into a `double` so I can compare it with my input value i.e., (25556.362) and select that particular value.

Comment: What have you tried? Please [edit] your question and include it. Does it work?

Comment: Once you have the single `option`s as `WebElement`s just extract their content with `getText()` and parse the result as a `double` with `Double.parseDouble`

Comment: Getting this Error..
"The method parseDouble(String) in the type Double is not applicable for the arguments (double, List<WebElement>)"

Comment: Getting this error with what code exactly? Why are you passing a `List` to `parseDouble`?

Comment: I'm working on Selenium Webdriver, & stuck on one task.
My actual scenario is - I've to Fetch Value that is in Double & compare that value with the data present in Web Application Dropdown List & select it proceed further...@Lutz Horn

Comment: Double.parseDouble(new StrikePriceMethod().getData0() , list);

@FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: @Pankaj again, why are you passing a `List` to `parseDouble`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, Read my last comment starts with "I'm working on Selenium"...

Hope you understand my exact concern

Comment: I do understand. But that code still makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

I would select the select list option using the xpath directly using the below xpath.

```
//select[@attribute='attribute_value']/option[normalize-space(.)='25556.362']
```

Make sure to replace the `attribute` and `attribute_value` in the above xpath based on the select element locator.

```
WebElement selectItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@attribute='attribute_value']/option[normalize-space(.)='25556.362']"));
// now click on the element to select
selectItem.click();
```

Comment: That is we can do in Scripting.

But I've to Fetch value directly from User & Select it accordingly...

@supputuri

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your comment. Do you mean get the value from the user in the run time?

Comment: I've to take value from Excel that User has entered & also read it from there & verify that Particular value from Web application's Dropdown list & if its get matched Select it & move further...@supputuri

Comment: You use `POI` to read the excel data and store the value in `String listItem` and then use the below `WebElement selectItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@attribute='attribute_value']/option[normalize-space(.)='" + listItem +"']"));`

Comment: My text is this = "BANKNIFTY-22AUG2019" that doesn't contains any spaces but very thanku for helping me with below code which not helpful for me.

Because if "AUG" gets changed into "SEP" then in future that code will gets unused..@supputuri

Comment: When you are reading the `listItem` value from excel or assigning in the script then why do you think it does not work. There is nothing to do with the xpath. Sorry, I am not sure your concern here. If the date is always currentdate+xday then you can add that logic in script and update the value to `listItem` which should work even when the date or month changes.